# Replace unicode chars in VIM?

Tags: vim

I got some logs from a Windows machine, which contains multiple instances of `<200e>`, I know it's a Unicode char, but how can I remove it with `s` command?

I don't know how to input that in the command line.

**EDIT**

This is a Unicode char, which means I can delete that with single `x` key pressing ... it's not 6 chars `<200e>` ...

Comment: have you check this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`:

> With CTRL-V the decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character can be
>   entered directly.  This way you can enter any character, except a line break
>   (, value 10). There are five ways to enter the character value:
>
> ```
> first char  mode         max nr of chars   max value
> ( none )    decimal        3               255
> o or O      octal          3               377      (255)
> x or X      hexadecimal    2               ff       (255)
> u           hexadecimal    4               ffff     (65535)
> U           hexadecimal    8               7fffffff (2147483647)
> ```

This means you can use `<Ctrl-v>u200e` to input the character and
use it as usual in substitute commands or elsewhere.

```
:%s/<Ctrl-v>u200e//g
```

Comment: There is also a regexp-specific way to denote extended characters, see `:help /\%u` (this lets you type without having to use C-v, i.e. it is easy to “paste”): `%s/\%u200e//g`

Comment: I've noticed that notation like \%u200e doesn't work if I use \v in front of it for extended regular expression. Would be great to know how to get it working...

Comment: thanks @ChrisJohnsen! this works perfectly for me! save a lot of time :-D